# Cannot run Jruby generated .war file on Tomcat (Windows)

Tags: tomcat, jruby

I did a command 'jruby -S warble' which generated .war file. And I deployed to tomcat server.  But then when I run the application got error messages like below.  Please let me know what I need to do.  Regards,

Application initialization failed: no such file to load -- rack from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/rouge/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.7.jar!/vendor/rack.rb:7 from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/rouge/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.7.jar!/vendor/rack.rb:28:in `require' from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/rouge/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.7.jar!/jruby/rack/booter.rb:28:in`boot!' from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/rouge/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.7.jar!/jruby/rack/boot/rack.rb:10 from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/rouge/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.7.jar!/jruby/rack/boot/rack.rb:1:in `load' from :1

Comment: It was issue of spaces in windows directory. Installed under c:/tomcat and works fine

Answer (score 0):

Run JRuby 1.6 (or the RC3 pre-release with `--pre`) where this bug is fixed.

```
jruby -S gem install -v '~> 1.6.0' jruby-jars
jruby -S gem install jruby-jars --pre
```